# Как оптимизировать перебор массива с поиском повторяющихся элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть начальный массив из 5 чисел, нужно найти в нем совпадающее число и вывести, если совпадающих чисел больше одного, то вывести число с максимальным количеством совпадений. Вариант когда количество совпадений у двух чисел одинаковое можно не рассматривать.
Написал вот такой код, он не универсальный, но с решением данной задачи справляется. Однако мне кажется, что он не самый оптимальный и можно сократить количество условий и придать какой-то универсальности. Может есть какие-то предложения?

```js
let answers = [2, 3, 3, 2, 3]
let sortAnswers = answers.sort((a, b) => a - b)
let number = null
let result = {
  number: [],
  score: []
}

for (let i = 0; i < sortAnswers.length; i++) {
  if (sortAnswers[i] === number) {
    if (result.number.length) {
      if (result.number[0] === sortAnswers[i]) {
        result.score[0]++
      } else if (result.number.length > 1 && result.number[1] === sortAnswers[i]) {
        result.score[1]++
      } else {
        result.number.push(sortAnswers[i])
        result.score.push(1)
      }
    } else {
      result.number.push(sortAnswers[i])
      result.score.push(1)
    }
  }

  number = sortAnswers[i]
}

console.log(sortAnswers, result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const maxNumberRepeat = (arr) => {
  let numObj = arr.reduce((acc,i) => {
    acc[i] ? acc[i]++ : acc[i]=1;
    return acc;
  },{}) // собираем объект в котором считаем количество цифр.
  const maxNumber = Math.max(...Object.values(numObj)); // находим максимальное повторения числа.
  return +Object.keys(numObj).find(key => numObj[key] === maxNumber); // возвращаем само число. 
}


console.log(maxNumberRepeat([2, 3, 3, 2, 3]))
console.log(maxNumberRepeat([4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1 , 6 , 7,  4, 2]))
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже смотрел в сторону reduce для перебора, но что-то не додумал, что можно само число в качестве ключа использовать)